# anchor to div id hides the element title

Tags: html, css

I want to scroll to the related div element on click of an anchor tag. but it hides the element when using without `overflow: hidden` attribute in `body` tag. And with `overflow: hidden` it hides the scrollbar.
you can understand by codes.

Please see this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/millerroy/wvjha7ep/11/).

Comment: There are a few mistakes in your html. I've tried to correct them [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/xs62muwk/).

"it hides the element" - are you referring to the element `<div id="a">`? If I remove `overflow: hidden` then everything works as I would expect, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Would you explain a bit more?

Comment: Setting `overflow` to `hidden` should do what it's doing - i.e. not creating scrollbars. Could you clarify what you mean by "it hides the element when using without"?